# Can't install Ubuntu with Graphics Card

Tags: hardware, 19.04

I tries this multiple times: I tried installing Ubuntu 19.04 on my PC, with my NVIDIA GTX 1050 as a graphics card. But when I try, I always get an error saying:

```
AMD-Vi: Completion-Wait loop timed out
```

and

```
usb usb1-port3: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

But I can install it, when my graphics card isn't built in. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Mobo from gigabyte? Then try bootoptions `amd_iommu=on iommu=pt`

Comment: And because Nvidia graphics you may also need `nomodeset` to install and in the first boot until the proper drivers are installed.